# Websocket.ReceiveAsync causing a crash when a client disconnects without cancelling connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

DotNet Core 3.1 (running either Kestral or IIS)

I have the following loop, running in a Task for each connected client

```
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                        do

                            webSocketReceiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                            ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, webSocketReceiveResult.Count);

                        }
                        while (!webSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage);
```

When a client abruptly exits, network failure, crash or whatever and doesnt have a chance to close its connection, it crashes the whole class, and all tasks running. The webserver is still up and will accept all new connections, but all existing connections are terminated.

The error is : 'The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.'
which is expected, but I cannot try-catch it to preserve the rest of the connections?

Complete method here:

```
    private static async Task SocketProcessingLoopAsync(ConnectedClient client)
    {
        _ = Task.Run(() => client.BroadcastLoopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));

        var socket = client.Socket;
        var loopToken = SocketLoopTokenSource.Token;
        var broadcastTokenSource = client.BroadcastLoopTokenSource; // store a copy for use in finally block
        string sessionName = "";
        string command = "";
        int commandCounter = 0;
        WebSocketReceiveResult webSocketReceiveResult = null;
        try
        {



            var buffer = WebSocket.CreateServerBuffer(4096);

            while (socket.State != WebSocketState.Closed && socket.State != WebSocketState.Aborted && !loopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                // collect all the bytes incoming

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                        do
                        {
                            webSocketReceiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                            ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, webSocketReceiveResult.Count);

                        }
                        while (!webSocketReceiveResult.EndOfMessage);

                    //var receiveResult = await client.Socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, loopToken);

                    // if the token is cancelled while ReceiveAsync is blocking, the socket state changes to aborted and it can't be used
                    if (!loopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        // the client is notifying us that the connection will close; send acknowledgement
                        if (client.Socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived && webSocketReceiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Socket {client.SocketId}: Acknowledging Close frame received from client");
                            broadcastTokenSource.Cancel();
                            await socket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Acknowledge Close frame", CancellationToken.None);
                            // the socket state changes to closed at this point
                        }


                        if (client.Socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                        {
                            if (webSocketReceiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                            {
                                // here we receive text instructioons from the clients

                                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                                {
                                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    command = reader.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
                                }

                                //   var command = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, webSocketReceiveResult.Count).ToLower();
                                if (command.Contains("session:"))
                                {
                                    // assign the client to a session, and inform them of their position in it
                                    sessionName = command.Replace("session:", "");
                                    if (!ClientControl.Sessions.ContainsKey(sessionName))
                                    {
                                        ClientControl.Sessions.TryAdd(sessionName, new BlockingCollection<ConnectedClient>());
                                    }
                                    ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].Add(client);
                                    // broadcast the collection count
                                    Broadcast(ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].Count.ToString(), client, true, sessionName);
                                    Broadcast("Number of clients " + ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].Count.ToString(), client, false, sessionName);
                                    Broadcast("Number of clients " + ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].Count.ToString(), client, true, sessionName);
                                }
                                else if (command.Contains("status:"))
                                {
                                    string output = "<br/><h1>Sessions:</h1><br/><br/>";
                                    foreach (var session in ClientControl.Sessions)
                                    {
                                        output += session.Key + " Connected Clients: " + session.Value.Count.ToString() + "<br/>";

                                    }

                                    Broadcast(output, client, true, "");
                                }
                                else if (command.Contains("ping"))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(command + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + commandCounter);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // we just mirror what is sent out to the connected clients, depending on the session

                                Broadcast(ms.ToArray(), client, sessionName);
                                commandCounter++;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }// end memory stream 

            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Socket {client.SocketId}:");
            Program.ReportException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            broadcastTokenSource.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine($"Socket {client.SocketId}: Ended processing loop in state {socket.State}");

            // don't leave the socket in any potentially connected state
            if (client.Socket.State != WebSocketState.Closed)
                client.Socket.Abort();

            // by this point the socket is closed or aborted, the ConnectedClient object is useless
            if (ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].TryTake(out client))
                socket.Dispose();

            // signal to the middleware pipeline that this task has completed
            client.TaskCompletion.SetResult(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can check this as a sample: https://github.com/georgekosmidis/AspNetCore.WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

Ok, couldn't get this to work, I have re-written the loop to look like this, it exits cleanly when a client hangs

```
  do
                    {
                        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);

                        task = socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, loopToken);
                        while (!task.IsCompleted && !SocketLoopTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(2).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        if (socket.State != WebSocketState.Open || task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                        {
                            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Socket {client.SocketId}: Acknowledging Close frame received from client");
                                broadcastTokenSource.Cancel();
                                await socket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Acknowledge Close frame", CancellationToken.None);
                                ClientControl.Sessions[sessionName].TryTake(out client);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Client Left " + client.SocketId);
                            break;
                        }
                        ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, task.Result.Count);

                    }
                    while (!task.Result.EndOfMessage);
```