# C# websockets buffer size is not big enough

Tags: c#

the buffer size is limited by 16000 bytes but the full received messeage is over 25000 bytes big
because of this i get only the half received message.

my code:

```
ArraySegment<byte> LogInByteToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(LogInData[i]));
await Ws.SendAsync(LogInByteToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cTs.Token);

var responseBuffer = new byte[17000];
var offset = 0;
var packet = 16000;
while (true)
{
     ArraySegment<byte> CastleDataByteReceived = new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer, offset, packet);
     WebSocketReceiveResult response = await Ws.ReceiveAsync(CastleDataByteReceived, cTs.Token);
     var raw_gbd_msg_byte_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, offset, response.Count);
```

Comment: You have to keep reading until all the message has been received, there's an example at [Websocket.ReceiveAsync causing a crash when a client disconnects without cancelling connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076979/websocket-receiveasync-causing-a-crash-when-a-client-disconnects-without-cancell).